# Is there a correct way to ensure a Swift array copy?

Tags: arrays, swift, pointers

For example when manipulating the underlying data via an `UnsafeMutablePointer`...

```
// Using Swift 2.2
import Foundation

let a = [1, 2, 3]
var aCopy = a
let aCopyPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(aCopy)

let b = [4, 5, 6]
let bPointer = UnsafePointer<Int>(b)

let bData = NSData(bytes: bPointer, length: sizeof(Int) * b.count)
bData.getBytes(aCopyPointer, length: sizeof(Int) * b.count)

print(a) // [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value types, and `Array` among them, are copy **on-write**.  Therefore, you can get what you want with:

```
import Foundation

let a = [1, 2, 3]
var aCopy = a
aCopy[0] = aCopy[0] // <- just to trigger the copying
let aCopyPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(aCopy)

let b = [4, 5, 6]
let bPointer = UnsafePointer<Int>(b)

let bData = NSData(bytes: bPointer, length: sizeof(Int) * b.count)
bData.getBytes(aCopyPointer, length: sizeof(Int) * b.count)

print(a) // [1, 2, 3]
```

Although, I think it make sense to make a feature request at Swift Evolution for an API to explicitly request a copy of a value type.  The trick above does work for now, but the compilers tend to get smarter, and one day you might get different behaviour due to some cool optimization.

Comment: Unsafe pointers are called unsafe exactly for the reason that anything can happen when you fiddle with them.  Implicitly copying the whole array just because you get an unsafe pointer to it can be quite expensive sometimes, while the reason why people resort to the use of said pointers is typically performance-driven.

Comment: Actually, having thought about it some more – you're dead right (I have deleted my previous comment). This should really just be an explicit feature rather than an implicit behaviour when working with unsafe pointers. Although a clever compiler optimisation would always be nice.